# WP_Query author parameter not working

Tags: wp-query, author

As per doumentation

Author Parameters #Author Parameters

1. author (int) – use author id.
2. author_name (string) – use ‘user_nicename‘ – NOT name.
3. author__in (array) – use author id (available since version 3.7).
4. author__not_in (array) – use author id (available since version
   3.7).

Can they all work together?

If I keep author__not_in, first 3 does not work? author__not_in is an empty array

Comment: Can you give a realistic sample of what posts you would be looking for then, exactly? Having author__not_in set for what would you need to use the 3 others then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the `author` parameter is parsed and appended to the `author__in` and `author__not_in` query parameters.

Then `author__in` or `author__not_in` array is processed. These can be arrays created from `author` parameter or arrays passed as query parameteres `author__in` / `author__not_in` **or created from a mergion** `author` parameter with `author__in` / `author__not_in` parameters.

Parameters `author__in` and `author__not_in` are mutually exclusive, so you can use only one of them. If both are given, then `author__not_in` will be used.

Finally, the `author_name` parameter is processed and added to the`where` clause. Although theoretically it can be used with any of the other parameters, the effect will be the same as if only `author_name` was used.